# successHandler in Spring Boot Oauth2 using ADFS

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2, adfs, spring-oauth2

I am using ADFS as an Identity provider and using Oauth2 with Spring Boot as a client. We have provided a Redirect URI to ADFS as {baseURI}/SSO. Currently I have configured like below in my application.properties.

1. Application.properties configuration

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-id=<Client_id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-secret=<sceret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.redirect-uri=<redirect_URI>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom.authorization-uri=<authorization_uri>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom.token-uri=<token_uri>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom.user-info-uri=<user_info_URI>
```

2)I am able to generate an Oauth login page

3. User is able to login and then redirects to the configured redirect URI where I have created a Java Controller. Post login from ADFS IDP the response comes back on my server back and hits the below congtroller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/sso")
    public void login(@RequestParam String code, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setAccessControlAllowOrigin("*");
        String message = "Welcome to MMS SSO to ABSLI. Your access Code id "+ code;
        LOGGER.debug(code);
        ABSLIIdTokennModel tokenParam = new ABSLIIdTokennModel();
        tokenParam.setCode(code);

        response.addHeader("authorization-code", code);
        try {
            response.sendRedirect("https://absli-claims-dev.metamorphosys.co.in/#/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return new ResponseEntity<>(message, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

4. from this Java controller then I redirect to my Angular 10 app.

below is my security config

```
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**","/sso**","/sso/**", "/token**", "/signup**", "/signin**", "/verify**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .authorizationEndpoint();

        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

But now I want to add a successHandler with some custom logic once the user is logged in.

My question is when this successhandler will be invoked? After the user is redirected to my redirect_URI or before the redirect URI is hit?

And if successhandler invokes before my redirect URI controller is hit then do I really need the /sso controller?

May I know the implementation of successhandler handler with redirect-uri in Oauth2 Spring?

Thanks in avance.